# PHP form that shows extra content based on user's response (pt. 2)

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements

When a user fills out this simple radio button form, they need to be shown the link at the bottom only if they a click yes for each and every question.  I'm getting some syntax errors when I run this.  Noob at PHP!

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<div><br>
<p>Question 1?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 2?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 3?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 4?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"> No<br>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['group1']) && isset($_POST['group2']) && isset($_POST['group3']) && isset($_POST['group4'])) {
    if ($_POST['group1']=='Yes' && $_POST['group2']=='Yes') && ($_POST['group3']=='Yes' && ($_POST['group4']=='Yes' print '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the extra content after selecting yes for all questions before or after the user submits the form? If you don't want the page to refresh and prefer PHP to handle the decision making, look into ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS/jQuery solution http://jsfiddle.net/nH8Xq/

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<div><br>
<p>Question 1?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 2?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 3?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 4?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"> No<br>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<div id="link">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if(
        ($('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group2]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group3]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group4]:checked').val() == 'Yes')
    ){
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = '';
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing `)` in the second if statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['group1']) && isset($_POST['group2']) && isset($_POST['group3']) && isset($_POST['group4'])) {
    if ($_POST['group1']=='Yes' && $_POST['group2']=='Yes') && ($_POST['group3']=='Yes' && ($_POST['group4']=='Yes' ) print '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not close your second if properly:

```
if ($_POST['group1']=='Yes' 
   && $_POST['group2']=='Yes') 
   && ($_POST['group3']=='Yes' 
   && ($_POST['group4']=='Yes' 
    print '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
```

try:

```
if ($_POST['group1']=='Yes' 
   && $_POST['group2']=='Yes'
   && $_POST['group3']=='Yes' 
   && $_POST['group4']=='Yes') 
    print '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
```

Note that your link will be shown after the form has been sent-> on the next page. To show it on the same page you will need javaScript involved.

Also as a tip: try to enter linebreaks in long if clauses to increase readability which will prevent loosing the overview. For some good practices look here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php.

Answer (score 0):

this looks a tad backwards - php is (typically) interpreted on the server before the page is sent to the browser. your web form is on the browser but won't have any of the php code. if you want to display something based on user input you're better off using javascript (or similar).

Comment: not true, if you want the form action to point to the same page then then you can leave action attribute empty.

Comment: I'm definitely interested in a javascript solution for this @ethrbunny.  Mind helping me out as to how that would look?